# Wordpress: slow edit post

Tags: php, wordpress, performance

We're managing a wordpress website but since a specific post, new posts are very slow to edit.

With the plugin "Query monitor", I tried to understand what's going on, but I can't find anything interesting.

A post that is normal :
1.21s of loading
85 000kb Memory Usage
0,4139 Databse query time

with only 1 slow query (meta_form() function in wp-admin/includes/templates.php)

In the post and after:
2,5s of loading (In reality, it takes more than a minute and a half to stop loading)
256 000kb Memory usage
1,0208 Databse query time

with 4 slow queries

[image]

Comment: Meta Queries in WP can be *very* slow, and it looks like several of them are running. Where are both of the `update_meta_cache` callers coming from? A plugin or core? That's a duplicate query in itself and `has_meta()` could be derived from one of the existing meta queries occurring (if you have access to the methods calling it)

Comment: @TyBailey This is from Core wordpress and that only occured since this post. Bellow this, we have no issues. Any clue ?